# Open file edit save changes with new name same location

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel VBA file which I open from Location D:/Folder-A/File Workbook-1.  I perform operations and data entries.  I save the file back to same location.  After I save the edited original file, I clear contents of range cells to Obtain a blank original template ready for new data entries.  Once the contents are cleared, I need to safe the workbook to the same original file location, but with a new name, say Workbook-2.  I can bring open the original file and edit and save to original location, but once I make the final change to clear contents, I need to save the final changes to the same location, but with a new workbook name.

Comment: `File.SaveAs` perhaps?

Comment: I will try - thanks